# Execution of 'You lost' loop in Hangman game despite winning the game on the last try

Tags: python, debugging, control-flow, logic-error

I have been trying to build a Hangman game, but I am facing a problem. The game runs fine, but every time I guess the word on my last chance, instead of the “You won!” block being executed, the “You lost! Try again” block gets executed. I have added the source code and and the output below. I am guessing that I need to use a continue or break function somewhere, but I don't know for sure.

```py
import random

animals = """lion tiger elephant giraffe monkey zebra cheetah bear wolf gorilla
dolphin kangaroo penguin owl fox rabbit horse lionfish eagle shark"""
animals_list = animals.split()
word = random.choice(animals_list)

for _ in word:
    print("_", end=" ")
print()
print()

chances = len(word) + 2
winnings = 0
letter_guessed = ""

try:
    while chances != 0 and winnings == 0:
        chances -= 1
        print(f"Chances remaining: {chances}")

        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        print()

        if len(guess) != 1 or not guess.isalpha():
            print("Please enter a single letter!")
            print()
            continue

        if guess in letter_guessed:
            print("You have already guessed that letter!")
            continue

        if guess in word:
            print("Correct!")
            print()
            letter_guessed += guess

            if letter_guessed == word:
                print("The word is", word)
                print("You won!")
                winnings += 1
            else:
                for letter in word:
                    if letter in letter_guessed:
                        print(letter, end=" ")
                    else:
                        print("_", end=" ")
                print()
        else:
            print("Wrong guess!")
            print()
            letter_guessed += guess

    if chances == 0 and letter_guessed != word and winnings == 0:
        print("You lost!")
        print("Better luck next time!")
        print("The word was", word)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
    print("Bye! Try again, please!")
```

I got this as output:

---

```
Chances remaining: 4
Guess a letter: g

Wrong guess!

Chances remaining: 3
Guess a letter: d

Wrong guess!

Chances remaining: 2
Guess a letter: f

Correct!

f _ _ 
Chances remaining: 1
Guess a letter: o

Correct!

f o _ 
Chances remaining: 0
Guess a letter: x

Correct!

f o x 
You lost!
Better luck next time!
The word was fox
```

Comment: After these 5 guesses, what's in your `letter_guessed` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
letter_guessed = ""
```

To

```
letter_guessed = set()
```

And then change

```
letter_guessed += guess
```

To

```
letter_guessed.add(guess)
```

Here is the full code

```
import random

animals = """lion tiger elephant giraffe monkey zebra cheetah bear wolf gorilla
dolphin kangaroo penguin owl fox rabbit horse lionfish eagle shark"""
animals_list = animals.split()
word = random.choice(animals_list)
for _ in word:
    print("_", end=" ")
print()
print()

chances = len(word) + 2
winnings = 0
letter_guessed = set()


try:
    while chances != 0 and winnings == 0:
        chances -= 1
        print(f"Chances remaining: {chances}")

        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        print()

        if len(guess) != 1 or not guess.isalpha():
            print("Please enter a single letter!")
            print()
            continue

        if guess in letter_guessed:
            print("You have already guessed that letter!")
            continue

        if guess in word:
            print("Correct!")
            print()
            for _ in  range(word.count(guess)):
                letter_guessed.add(guess)

            if letter_guessed == set(word):
                print("The word is", word)
                print("You won!")
                winnings += 1
            else:
                for letter in word:
                    if letter in letter_guessed:
                        print(letter, end=" ")
                    else:
                        print("_", end=" ")
                print()
        else:
            print("Wrong guess!")
            print()

    if chances == 0 and letter_guessed != word and winnings == 0:
        print("You lost!")
        print("Better luck next time!")
        print("The word was", word)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
    print("Bye! Try again, please!")
```

---

The Problems in you code

1. You are adding guess in letter_guess even it is wrong guess

Here

```py
else:
    print("Wrong guess!")
    print()
    letter_guessed += guess # here so (I have remove it)
```

2. Your code adds only one guess letter even if there are multiply guess letter in `word`

Example:

```
word = "apple"
# and the user guess 'p', then in letter_guess you have to add `p` two times but your code only adding it one time
```

Comment: Also, you (correctly) removed `letter_guessed += guess` from the `else` block.

Comment: `for _ in  range(word.count(guess)):` There's no need for the loop here: adding the same item to a set multiple times is the same as adding it once.

Comment: @slothrop Yeah, Sorry I forgot that LOL, I have change it now

Comment: @slothrop Yeah I have removed it but, now mentioned it